# Need Help Implementing a Rolling window | IndexError: Index 52 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, statsmodels

I'm running into an indexing error when trying to implement a rolling window for my data regression results.

For example, I'm trying to run a rolling regression from weeks 1-52, 2-53, 3-54, 4-55... and so on.

Here is the code that I have so far.
For `data=rolling_window.iloc[y:x]`, how would I increase both y and x by +1 on a loop until the end of the data? Ie [2:53], [3:54]... I tried using the two x,y for loops but it does not work.

Here is the error

```
index 52 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14
```

Here is the code.

```
df = pd.read_excel("dataset\Special_Proj.xlsx") 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')


def rolling_regression_stats():
    tickers = df[['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']]

    rolling_window = df
    for y in range(1, 1161):
        for x in range(52, 1161):
            for t in tickers:
                model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=rolling_window.iloc[y,x]).fit()
                coef_and_intercept = model.params.set_axis([f'{t} Alpha', f'{t} Beta']).to_string()
                std_error = model.bse.set_axis([f'{t} Alpha STD Err ', f'{t} Beta STD Err']).to_string()
                print(coef_and_intercept)
                print(std_error, '\n\n')

rolling_regression_stats()
```

Here is the output of the code without the x, y for loops. This is just a regression of the dataframe.

```
FDX Alpha    10.285265
FDX Beta      2.332717
FDX Alpha STD Err     4.826221
FDX Beta STD Err      0.035187


BRK Alpha   -58.007537
BRK Beta      2.916011
BRK Alpha STD Err     3.007438
BRK Beta STD Err      0.021927


MSFT Alpha   -113.047496
MSFT Beta       1.794111
MSFT Alpha STD Err     2.559493
MSFT Beta STD Err      0.018661
```

Here is what the df looks like for reference.

```
        Date        SP50         FDX         BRK        MSFT        NVDA        INTC         AMD         JPM           T        AAPL        AMZN          GS    
0 1999-12-31  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000 NaN
1 2000-01-07   98.109239  116.030534  100.713012   95.449679   89.214380   99.620349  112.311015   93.644406   90.512812   96.778115   91.379310   87.657598 NaN
2 2000-01-14   99.720946  113.740458   93.048128   96.145610   93.608522  125.208808  139.524838   95.092516   86.025639   97.689969   84.400657   90.909091 NaN
3 2000-01-21   98.101753  101.984733   94.295900   88.865096   95.339553  118.982536  131.317495   93.885758   88.205127  108.267481   81.527094   90.975448 NaN
4 2000-01-28   92.575123   94.198473   93.226381   84.154176   79.627162  114.198937  121.814255   98.712789   80.512815   98.844983   81.034485   92.368945 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does a rolling regression.

```
def rolling_regression_stats():
    tickers = df[['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']]

    rolling_window = df
    iterable = zip(range(1110), range(52,1162))
    for y, x in iterable:
        for t in tickers:
            model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data= rolling_window.iloc[y:x]).fit()
            coef_and_intercept = model.params.set_axis([f'{t} Alpha', f'{t} Beta']).to_string()
            std_error = model.bse.set_axis([f'{t} Alpha STD Err ', f'{t} Beta STD Err']).to_string()
            print(coef_and_intercept)
            print(std_error, '\n\n')
```